# 403 Forbiden Error: urllib fails to work on aws lambda to scrape www.avvo.com

Tags: python, aws-lambda, urllib

I'm running a Python scraper that works perfectly on my local machine (windows) but when the same script is deployed to AWS lambda, it throws `403 Forbiden Error` by making just a single test request through urllib module to [www.avvo.com](http://www.avvo.com).

**Code:**

```
import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    url = 'https://www.avvo.com/attorneys/84025-ut-jason-hunter-284784.html#client_reviews'

    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }

    with urlopen(Request(url, headers=headers)) as response:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), features="html.parser")

        data = {}

        data["website"] = soup.title.text
    
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": json.dumps(data)
    }
```

**Error:**

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden",
  "errorType": "HTTPError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 27, in lambda_handler\n    with urlopen(Request(url, headers=headers)) as response:\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py\", line 222, in urlopen\n    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py\", line 531, in open\n    response = meth(req, response)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py\", line 640, in http_response\n    response = self.parent.error(\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py\", line 569, in error\n    return self._call_chain(*args)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py\", line 502, in _call_chain\n    result = func(*args)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py\", line 649, in http_error_default\n    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting when you run it on the Lambda?

Comment: This is the API I have created for this scraper on AWS. Check the error here https://bgdm8mz5m0.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/reviews/avvo-api?url=attorneys/84025-ut-jason-hunter-284784.html#client_reviews

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear: One of the URLs you are trying to crawl is protected. Therefore, you are getting a `403 Forbidden` error.

So you need to make sure that you handle those errors. Might be a good idea to log the URLs that can't be crawled.

Comment: Thank you so much for the editing part. Moreover, the same script don't create any issues when I run it on windows but on AWS returns the error "403 Forbidden". After some reseach I have come to know that the package I deployed to AWS is created on windows so it might be the modules dependencies issues installed. 

So I'm going to setup the package on docker and then deploy to AWS. I hope it will run perfectly.

Comment: `urllib` is part of the standard library and therefore it does not matter if you created it on windows. At least this part. And you would get a completely different error when you would load a library that was compiled for a different kernel (like windows) or architecture (like amd64). Your problem is still that you don't have permission to access the page. This might be, because they block AWS IP ranges. That's why it works on your local machine and not your Lambda. I had something like this once.

Comment: Refering to your last statment "I had something like this once.", would you like to explain it further? I'm interested to know how did you solve this issue on AWS?

Comment: Not in the comments @MujahidAlkausari. Create a simple demo Lambda that reproduces the bug. Just the HTTP call to show that the call fails in AWS but not on a local machine. Maybe create a easy to use Terraform/CloudFormation project so that people can reproduce it themselves and then create a new question with all of this.

Comment: Good suggestion. I will post a new simplified version of it in a new question thread. Thanks for the help. Thumbs up!!!